# 'dynamic' images overlapping not dispalying horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Im trying to display images side by side but there displaying ontop of each other. I have a div that I append img tags to using angularJS and Im not sure if its becasue they are appended seperately and therefore get layered ontop of each other or if its because of my css.

I append to the div by this:

```
for(var i = 0;i < data.list.length;i++) 
        {
            $scope.HTML = $sce.trustAsHtml('<img id="images"  src="http://localhost:8080/images/'+data.list[i]+'"/>');
        }
```

The div itself in the HtML looks like:

```
<div id="section" ng-bind-html="HTML">
</div>
```

Then my css looks like this:

```
#section {
    width:90%;
    height:35%;
    margin:auto;
    min-width:600px;
    max-width:2000px
    padding:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: grey;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#images{
    height: 75%;
    display: inline;
    float:auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

So what I have is:
[image: overlap]
and what im trying to do:
[image]
I thought that disply:inline; would enable this side by side but i doesnt.
Any help would be appreciatted.

Comment: Did you try to change `float` to `left` or `right`?

Comment: It seems to work fine... http://jsfiddle.net/dpLvhs3a/

Comment: I see it works from the fiddle so at least I know its not the HTML or CSS. It must be the angular injection. Would the inline-block work on the $scope.HTML call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are changing the value of the `$scope.HTML` each time `for~ loop iterates.

Try this:

```
$scope.HTML = [];
for(var i = 0;i < data.list.length;i++) 
    {
        $scope.HTML.push("http://localhost:8080/images/"+data.list[i]);
    }
```

And in your view:

```
<div id="section" ng-repeat="img in HTML">
    <img class="images" ng-src="{{img}}"/>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** Your `images` should be a CSS class not id

EDIT: For not having `div` for each `img`:

```
<div id="section">
    <img ng-repeat="img in HTML" class="images" ng-src="{{img}}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but it creates a new <div> for each image. But all the images are displaying so thank you.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much I'm pretty new to angular so I'm still learning. Thanks again!